# Programmatically styling Android's CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, styling

I got a class which extends Activity and programmatically adding some View items.

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this, null, android.R.style.Widget_CompoundButton_Star);
```

I'd like to set some checkBoxes styled as the Android SDK stars. I can't see any check box after I set its style to that Widget_CompoundButton_Star. Although that SDK style apparently works when directly placing in a xml.

Am I missing something here? THX

// As Pragnani said. Using `android.R.attr.starStyle` instead works.

Comment: do you add checkbox in Activity View? Post some more code

Comment: Yea, I did. When I use CheckBox(Context) constructor it works flawlessly. However, when explicitly set the style in the three parameter constructor item doesn't appear.

Comment: @Yuri may that style not compitable for checkbox...

Comment: CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(int); With that exact style defined in a XML works. So I guess that style is compatible with checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've arrived here looking for styling the text of the CheckBox instead of the Drawable, and I find the solution by another way. But hey! Let me share the solution to the myself of the future.

Instead of:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this, null, R.style.yourstyle);
```

Use:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
cb.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.yourstyle);
```

Hope it helps to solve the topic of the question!

Answer (score 11):

You can set style to view programmatically with ContextThemeWrapper.

```
CheckBox mCheckBox = new CheckBox(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyCheckBox));
```

Comment: This is a great way to get the view, but it also causes this particular warning

W/ResourceType: Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010034

So there may need to be another way to handle it rather than this.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CheckBoxStyle))
```