# material checkbox style after customize

Tags: android, android-custom-view, androidx, material-components, material-components-android

My customized checkbox (`MyCheckbox`) has extended from `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`, but the default styles don't apply to it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckboxTheme</item>
    <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/CheckboxTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckboxTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
     <!-- for example try to change background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

but did not change anything in preview and runtime.

Also, I migrated on MaterialComponent (extending from `com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox`) version:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01
```

and using `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox` for style. but DIDN'T change.

**NOTE:**
This issue fixes just when I mentioned the style for each instance:

```
            <com.something.MyCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some thing"
                style="@style/CheckboxTheme"
             />
```

**but I want to set this style for all instances of this class.**
Could you help me?

Comment: can you confirm this problem exist in `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03` ?

Comment: are you sure? I just tested it and view's background new is primary color. Even don't need to add style tag in xml layout. maybe you add this style in v21 and test it on api<21

Comment: No. It was a bug on the used version and fixed in version `1.2.0-alpha03`. Thanks @SinaDarvishi

Answer (score 7):

The `MaterialCheckBox` provided by the Material Components library uses the `checkboxStyle` attribute defined in the theme.
Just override this attribute to define globally the style in your app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <!-- .... -->
   <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckBox</item>
</style>
```

If you want to customize the color you can use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute in the style:

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
   <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.CheckBox</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.CheckBox" parent="">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/....</item>   <!-- checked -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/.....</item>  <!-- unchecked -->
  </style>
```

You can also apply the style to the single checkbox using:

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    style="@style/MyCheckBox"
    ..>
```

As alternative you can also use the `android:theme` in the layout, but it doesn't work globally.

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.CheckBox"/>
```

Just a note.
The colorTint selector is defined programmatically in the `MaterialCheckBox` code. You can also define a custom colorTint selector adding the `buttonTint` attribute in your custom style. In this case the colors defined above are ignored.

Comment: I use the exact codes you have provided, both global and single solution but, the checked one is gray! + And by using `buttonTint`, the `enabled="false"` doesn't affect on the checkbox itself; Only on the text; Makes it gray or normal.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951571/2389923), I tried using `ContextThemeWrapper` to apply the style:

```
class MyCheckbox @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                        defStyle: Int = 0)
: MaterialCheckBox(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CheckboxTheme), attrs, defStyle)
```