# Change Checkbox color only in checked state and disable user interaction

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I want to change the checkbox color to blue only when it is in checked state, at present "buttontint" make the default color too to blue so please tell me how to do that and i also want to disable it from touches like noone can manually check it so what to do in that case?

Edit:
I tried this style:

```
<style name="MyCheckbox" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/check_border</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/buy_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/check_border</item>
    </style>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Are you using the Material Components Library?

Comment: not for this activity

Comment: With AppCompat just override with a theme the accentColor. With a Material Components Theme check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520384/material-checkbox-style-after-customize/59534174#59534174)

Comment: but this will effect the whole application, i can't do that

Comment: Inside your Checkbox XML tag you can add a custom theme or style for that chexbox only

Comment: i did but it is not working @ChristianoBolla

Comment: @CosmicDev Did you read the answer? You can apply the style to the single checkbox or you can override the color with android:theme in the single checkbox. Same way with an AppCompat theme but just use the accentColor.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes i have also updated what i have tried so far please check.

Comment: Did you apply it with android:theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the color in the single checkbox using:

**AppCompat theme**:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LABEL"
    android:checked="true"
    android:theme="@style/OverlayCheckbox"/>
```

with:

```
<style name="OverlayCheckbox">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light</item>
</style>
```

With a **Material Components Theme**:

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.CheckBox"/>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.CheckBox" parent="">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/....</item>   <!-- checked -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/.....</item>  <!-- unchecked -->
  </style>
```

With the Material Components Theme pay attention if you have defined the `colorAccent` in your app theme (you shouldn't add it in non-bridged Material Components theme).
In this case (I don't know if it is a [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1378) or if it is an expected behavior) the MaterialCheckbox uses the `colorAccent` instead of the `colorSecondary`. Just add the `colorAccent` or `colorControlActivated` in the `ThemeOverlay.CheckBox`.

Comment: working thank you and Gabriele what about my second query how can i programmatically check it but can stop the user from checking it?

Comment: Just use: checkBox.setEnabled(false);

Comment: @CosmicDev do you have the attribute colorAccent defined in the material component app theme?

Comment: @CosmicDev I think it is a bug. You can check this issue on [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1378). The `colorAccent` shouldn't be defined in the material components theme. In this case the `MaterialCheckbox` uses it (or it depends by the order used in the app theme. In the meanwhile you can add the `colorAccent` in the `ThemeOverlay.CheckBox`

Comment: The problem seems to with Material Theme itself, it does not allow to override the colorAccent of the predefined theme so they gave this option.

Comment: I have tried by adding colorAccent it is not working but my solution is, read this for more : https://material.io/develop/android/components/checkbox/

Comment: @CosmicDev It is not exactly the same. With `useMaterialThemeColors`=`false` you have to define your `button_tint` attibute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215992/discussion-between-cosmic-dev-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Answer (score 1):

test it

change color text and box

```
 if (checkBoxState == true){
            checkBox.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            checkBox.setEnabled(false);
        }else {
            checkBox.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

or

```
    <style name="changebox">
    <item name="colorAccent">#111</item>
</style>
```

.

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/changebox"/>
```

Comment: i don't have to change textcolor i have to change checkbox color